# Как узнать угол между вектором взгляда и точкой, используя любой язык?

Tags: математика, геометрия, любой-язык

Разрабатываю игру. Появилась необходимость найти угол между вектором направления взгляда персонажа и центром объекта, но не понимаю как это сделать.

Ниже приведу схему (вид сверху) для наглядности вопроса:

***a*** - вектор направления взгляда
***B*** - точка, центр объекта, к которому надо найти угол
***c*** - вектор ***a***, повернутый на необходимый градус
***α*** - угол, необходимый для поворота вектора ***a*** так, чтобы он смотрел на ***B***

Известны позиции: вектора ***a***, точки ***B***. Еще известен угол поворота вектора ***a*** вокруг своей оси.

Проблема возникает из-за того что я не знаю длину вектора ***a***, здесь он нарисован просто для визуализации проблемы.

[image: Схема]

Comment: Посчитайте угол между любым (например, единичным) вектором, отложенным от позиции вектора `a` в направлении его нулевого угла поворота и вектором, отложенным от позиции вектора `a` до точки `B` по формуле вычисления угла между векторами https://ru.onlinemschool.com/math/library/vector/angl/ Ну а затем к вычисленному углу просто добавьте угол поворота вектора `a`, который вам известен. Я просто не знаю, откуда вы считаете поворот вектора `a`, чтобы более конкретно сказать направление от которого всё считать.

Comment: 2D или 3D? Если 2D, то atan2. Но вообще-то в обоих случаях искать угол почти наверняка не надо.

Comment: @Qwertiy 3D, но я рассматриваю только две оси

Comment: @mirakoto, atan2.

Comment: @Qwertiy можете уточнить что к чему?

Comment: @mirakoto, ну две разности в него передать надо. И на выходе получится угол.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не могли бы вы объяснить с использованием данных в вопросе переменных?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант такой:
у вас есть вектора а.
Есть вектор b - он имеет начало в точке стояния вашего героя (точка глаз) и конец этого вектора в точке B.
Посчитаем, что система координат у вас новая, местная... и точка стояния вашего героя это нулевые координаты, так проще.
есть теорема, что скалярное произведение векторов:
a·b = x1*x2 + y1*y2 + z1*z2. a (x1, y1, z1) - вектор, b (x2, y2 ,z2) - вектор.
alpha - угол между двумя векторами.
cos(alpha) = (x1*x2 + y1*y2 + z1*z2) / (|a|*|b|). Где |a| и |b| - длины векторов.
Длина вектора равна квадратному корню из (x^2 + y^2 + z^2).

Comment: Он просил угол. Если применить arccos, то получится неверно в половине случаев, поскольку есть два угла, имеющих один и тот же косинус - ведь cos(x)=cos(-x). Аналогичная проблема будет с и с другими функциями. Поэтому для вычисления угла по координатам специально создана функция atan2 - вот её и надо использовать. Впрочем, крайне редко, потому что в большинстве реальных применений на самом деле нужен не угол, а нормированный вектор.

Comment: @Volk я пробовал использовать этот способ, однако при acos получается практически константное значение даже при больших изменениях

Comment: @mirakoto, надо разбираться, может где-то у вас ошибка. Не может быть константа.

Comment: @Volk я понял, что это происходит из-за того что тут не учитывается угол взгляда тела, т.е. надо повернуть не просто позицию тела a, но и его угол взгляда

Comment: @mirakoto, в целом, определение угла возможно по указанному выше методу, через аркос. Просто надо понять между чем и чем.

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен, что здесь есть такой момент, что косинус это четная функция, но! если мы говорим про угол между векторами, то это всегда угол от 0до 180 градусов. Соответственно, если он имеет отрицательное значение, значит он в диапазоне от 90 до 180 градусов.

Comment: @Volk, не уверен, насколько это верно математически (вроде тоже не похоже), но почти наверняка для реальных применений нужен угол из всего диапазона.

Comment: @Qwertiy, если говорит про 360 градусов. То угол между двумя векторами будет не вариант. (так как там до 180).